# Using Python to create a Unit Circle calculator?

Tags: python, math, trigonometry, fractions, symbolic-math

As a younger programmer, I'm always trying to look for applications of my skills.

Anyways, I'm currently taking trig and we're working on unit circles, the formula for converting from degrees to a coordinate is (sinθ, cosθ) (to the best of my knowledge).

However, the difficulty I'm having is that I need to keep the values as fractions.

Basically, the algorithm I've planned is:

```
i = 0
while i < 360:
    print(i, "=", calc(i))
    i += 15
```

Now, calc can be given any name, and will be a function that returns a coordinate (probably as a tuple) of x and y given x = sin θ and y = cos θ.

The issue I'm having is that sin in Python returns a floating point between -1 and 1, however, I need to find a way to have it return a fraction. For example, in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqp38.gif)  the coordinates are rational numbers.

What should I do? Should I write my own sine and cosine functions, and if so, how should I do that?

Comment: Only certain well-defined angles have rational trigonometric values.

Comment: `the coordinates are rational numbers.`. Wrong, its irrational. For example Root(3)/2 the x-cordinate for 30 degree is an irrational number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you need a third-party module such as [sympy](http://code.google.com/p/sympy/):

```
>>> import sympy
>>> for i in range(0, 360, 15):
...     print i, sympy.sin(sympy.Rational(i, 180) * sympy.pi)
...

0 0
15 sin(pi/12)
30 1/2
45 2**(1/2)/2
60 3**(1/2)/2
75 sin(5*pi/12)
90 1
105 sin(5*pi/12)
120 3**(1/2)/2
135 2**(1/2)/2
150 1/2
165 sin(pi/12)
180 0
195 -sin(pi/12)
210 -1/2
225 -2**(1/2)/2
240 -3**(1/2)/2
255 -sin(5*pi/12)
270 -1
285 -sin(5*pi/12)
300 -3**(1/2)/2
315 -2**(1/2)/2
330 -1/2
345 -sin(pi/12)
```

Comment: I didn't even know this module existed! This is why I love to read SO questions and answers, thank you Raymond.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try the [fraction](http://docs.python.org/library/fractions.html) module? I myself have never used it but goggled it in respect to this question.

Comment: Fraction won't help to represent irrational numbers as would be required by OP.

Comment: `fraction.gcd` is a good tool, though it will only express irrational numbers as best the computer can.

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I could think of is to take the decimal number and turn it into a fraction, just like you would in 6th grade. For instance .5 -> 1/.5 = 2 -> 1/2

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? A module which is written, tested and used by pros is available, then coming up with generic formulas is not much help.

Comment: I did not know there was a module for this, I was just simply explaining the programmatic way to accomplish this task. If it can be done easier, great! Less work for the programmer.

Comment: It's okay, but I don't know if this is even the best method, I wish it was possible to manipulate as a fraction from the beginning

Answer (score 0):

As Ignacio said in a comment, for most angles you *can't* represent the sine and cosine as a fraction, because they're irrational numbers. So writing your own sine and cosine functions won't help. (You could try it; it'd be an interesting exercise, but they would be pretty slow. The implementations of sine and cosine that are built into Python are written in C, based on code that's probably 40 years old, and generations of computer scientists have optimized the heck out of them so you probably can't do any better.)

As a matter of fact, even for angles that are a round number of degrees, you generally can't represent the sine and cosine as fractions, but in many cases you can represent their *squares* as fractions. So I would suggest calculating the sine squared and cosine squared. (Think about 45 degrees as an example)

Of course, even using a nice round angle, you're not going to get a fraction out of the (squared) sine and cosine functions because they return floating-point numbers. Your best bet is to convert the (approximate) decimal numbers into fractions. You can use the `fraction` module as suggested [by mangobug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8698590/56541) to do this; if you do, make liberal use of the `limit_denominator` function because you know that the fractions you're looking for have small denominators. Alternatively, you could write the algorithm yourself; that's another instructive exercise.

Finally, one tip: it's actually the x coordinate that corresponds to the cosine and the y coordinate to the sine, assuming your angles are defined the usual way.

Answer (score 0):

The following example to find the cos of 30 degree will help you understand how can you possibly do it

```
>>> angle=30*math.pi/180 #30 degree in randian
>>> cosine = math.cos(angle) #Lets find the cosine of 30 degree
>>> #Square it. Helps to represent a range of irrational numbers to rational numbers
>>> cos2 = cosine ** 2
>>> # Lets drop some precision. Don't forget about float approximation
>>> cos2 = round(cos2,4)
>>> num = fractions.Fraction(cos2).numerator #Just the Numerator of the fraction
>>> den = fractions.Fraction(cos2).denominator #The denominator of the fraction
>>> def PerfSquare(n): #Square root in an Integer
    return int(n**0.5)**2 == n
# If Perfect Square then Find the Square root or else represent as a root

>>> num = str(num**0.5) if PerfSquare(num) else "root{0}".format(num) # If Perfect Square then Find the Square root or else represent as a root
>>> den = str(den**0.5) if PerfSquare(den) else "root{0}".format(den)
>>> cos = "{0}/{1}".format(num,den) #Combine Numerator and Denominator
>>> print cos
root3/2.0
```

Here is a function by the above principle

```
>>> HIGHVALUE=1000
>>> def foo(degree,trigfn):
    angle=degree*math.pi/180 #in randian
    trigval = trigfn(angle) #Lets find the trig function
    #Square it. Helps to represent a range of irrational numbers to rational numbers
    trigval2 = trigval ** 2
    # Lets drop some precission. Don't forget about float aproximation
    trigval2 = round(trigval2,5)
    if trigval > HIGHVALUE:
        return u'\u221e'
    num = fractions.Fraction(trigval2).numerator #Just the Numerator of the fraction
    den = fractions.Fraction(trigval2).denominator #The denominator of the fraction
    if (num > HIGHVALUE or den > HIGHVALUE):
        trigval2 = round(1/trigval2,4)
        den = fractions.Fraction(trigval2).numerator #Just the Numerator of the fraction
        num = fractions.Fraction(trigval2).denominator #The denominator of the fraction
    if num > HIGHVALUE or den > HIGHVALUE or num < 1 or den < 1:
        #Cannot be represented properly
        #Just return the value
        return str(round(trigval,4))
    # If Perfect Square then Find the Square root or else represent as a root
    num = str(int(num**0.5)) if PerfSquare(num) else u"\u221a{0}".format(num)
    den = str(int(den**0.5)) if PerfSquare(den) else u"\u221a{0}".format(den)
    return u"{0}".format(num) if den == "1" else u"{0}/{1}".format(num,den) #Combine Numerator and Denominator
```

the result from the run

```
>>> def Bar():
    print 'Trig\t'+'\t'.join(str(x) for x in xrange(0,91,15))
    for fn in [math.sin,math.cos,math.tan]:
        print fn.__doc__.splitlines()[0],'\t',
        print '\t'.join(foo(angle,fn) for angle in xrange(0,91,15) )

>>> Bar()
Trig    0       15       30       45       60       75       90
sin(x)  0.0    0.2588    1/2    1/√2    √3/2    0.9659    1
cos(x)  1      0.9659    √3/2    1/√2    1/2    0.2588    0.0
tan(x)  0.0    0.2679    1/√3    1      √3    3.7321    ∞
```